# Setting max-width on element while preserving padding and using text-overflow

Tags: html, css, bulma

I'm using Bulma's [tag](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/tag/) component to add some tags to my website.

On mobile devices with small screens, the tags don't fit and go on the next line, and so I'm trying to set a max-width on the tag elements with an ellipsis. My goal is to have the tags appear like this when they can't fit, while still preserving the padding on the element, like so:

[image]

However, when I try to set these CSS properties:

```css
.tag-with-counts .tag {
  max-width: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I get something like this instead. The text does not start from the beginning, the padding isn't preserved, and ellipsis doesn't appear:

[image]

Here's a JSFiddle showing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljb2a0h7/1/

How can I make the tag appear as shown in the first image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text-overflow` property applies only to `block containers`.

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-4/#text-overflow

The display of your tag is `inline-flex` which generates a `flex container`. That's why `text-overflow` is not having any effect.

Comment: According to the standard ([https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#the-display-properties]), inline-flex generates an inline-level flex container, it does not generate a block container. That's why text-overflow doesn't work. inline-block works because it generates an inline-level block container, and as I've said in my answer you need a block-container for text-overflow to work. I do not see how it does not apply.

Comment: true but what I meant is that you aren't obliged to change the display for something different than inline-flex. It can still work with inline-flex but you need to consider an extra wrapper for text content because flex item will get blockified. Something you cannot do with only inline element whre you are obliged to change the display to something else

Comment: I see. You are correct. Calling them inline elements is incorrect (I was thinking only in terms of display: block and display: inline), as it doesn't really matter if it's inline but whether it generates a block context on the inside. I've corrected my answer. Thank you.